# How to wait for Java´s Desktop.getDesktop().browse() result?

Tags: java, asynchronous, wait

I am using `Desktop.getDesktop().browse("some URL")` and it is asynchronous, so any subsequent call will be in parallel to the browse() request.

How can I be sure `browse()` is finished, so I can continue only after it is done?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot and you should not :/ You have no means to know the user closes the browser window (or all windows) or browser's tab. And as well you should not force the user to close the browser completely. (I'd be pretty upset if I'd have to)

This command effectively sends a "open event" to the system with the URL parameter, so it works on all platforms which could open an URL.

What is the purpose  / why do you need to see if the browser is closed?

Now I will assume you want to do some data entry or authentication. I see mixed authentication (native app / web) using [OAuth 2.0 for installed applications](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-12) (Desktop or Mobile) so you coud take inspiration.

> How can I be sure browse() is finished, so I can continue only after it is done?

As described in the OAuth native app extension, you have two options:

1. regularily poll for the result for specific time (is user authenticated, are data entered)
2. providing a loopback address the web server could send the event to the server of the application (if there's any available)